# how to change string to array (hash)?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string that is divided by "," and now I want to take the string into array.

```
$text = "aaa, bbb, ccc"

$textArray = explode(",", $text); 
// -> array("aaa","bbb","ccc)
```

But, I what this string to like this.

```
// -> array("name" => array("aaa", "bbb" ,"ccc"))
```

Is there any php method to change the string into array like the above?

if not, what is the best way to implement this?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Thanks!! it should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want :

```
<?php
    $text = "aaa, bbb, ccc";
    $explode = explode(",", $text); 
    $textArray['name']=$explode ;
    print_r($textArray);

?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => aaa [1] => bbb [2] => ccc ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you tried this and did not like but look at it

```
$textArray = array('name' => explode(",", $text));
```

I think it does its job

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "aaa, bbb, ccc";

$textArray = explode(",", $text);

$Finalarr=''; $Finalarr['name']=$textArray;

echo ''; print_r($Finalarr);
```

Hope you like this.

Comment: Thanks!!! I need to learn more.